# Column header size when exporting radgrid to PDF

Tags: radgrid

I have a radgrid with autogenerated columns which should be exported to PDF, but when I export the grid when it contains many columns, the headers overlap each other. I want to control the size of the header text font.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the exporting command:

```
GridColumn column = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumn("Phone");
column.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(80);
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToPdf();
```